# split content of string by space to new line

Tags: php, string, split

I have `$str= "ns.kimsufi.com ks392904.kimsufi.com ks392904.kimsufi.com"`
I want to have them like that as string :

```
$str= "ns.kimsufi.com 
ks392904.kimsufi.com 
ks392904.kimsufi.com"
```

What is the easiest way to do such thing in PHP ?

Problem didn't solved...
Here is whole code :

```
<?php

$str= 'res Athéna 2 rue Henri Bergson<br/>
<b>Tech City: </b>STRASBOURG<br/>
<b>Tech State/Province:<br/>
</b><b>Tech Postal Code: </b>67200<br/>
<b>Tech Country:  </b>FR<br/>
<b>Tech Phone: </b>+33.679795486<br/>
<b>Tech Phone Ext:<br/>
</b><b>Tech Fax:<br/>
</b><b>Tech Fax Ext:<br/>
</b><b>Tech Email: </b><a href="mailto:fnt25qgfilw16kj60goe@h.o-w-o.info">fnt25qgfilw16kj60goe@h.o-w-o.info</a><br/>
<b>Name Server: </b><a href="/index.php?query=213.186.33.199&amp;output=nice">ns.kimsufi.com</a><br/>
<b>Name Server: </b><a href="/index.php?query=176.31.107.145&amp;output=nice">ks392904.kimsufi.com</a><br/>
<b>Name Server: </b><a href="/index.php?query=176.31.107.145&amp;output=nice">ks392904.kimsufi.com</a><br/>
<b>DNSSEC: </b>unsigned<br/>
<b>URL of the ICANN WHOIS Data Problem Reporting System:<br/>
</b><a href="http://wdprs.internic.net" target="_blank">http://wdprs.internic.net</a>/<br/>
>>> Last update of WHOIS database: 2015-06-07T10:20:36.0Z <br />
</td></tr>
</table><br />
<form name="queryform" method="post" action="/index.php">
<table cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="540" dir="ltr">
<tr><td bgcolor="#92CAFE">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" dir="ltr">
   <tr class="upperrow">
      <td align="left" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"><font face="Arial" size="+0"><b>Enter any domain name:</b></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="middlerow">
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap"><input type="text" name="query" value="" class="queryinput" />&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check Domain" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="lowerrow">
      <td align="right" valign="bottom"></td>
   </tr>
</table>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($str);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links = $xp->query('//b[text()="Name Server: "]/following-sibling::a[1]');




foreach ($links as $link) {
    $newlink = $link->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;

   $newlink = str_replace(' ', "\n", $newlink);

    echo $newlink;
}





?>
```

it still echo like that :

```
ns.kimsufi.com ks392904.kimsufi.com ks392904.kimsufi.com
```

what is the problem ?
if its not space between them what it is ?
any chance to change the code without using str_replace ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: You can't save multiline string like that.

Comment: want to send it to a database, and also wanted to see each one in new line in the page when I echo $str.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace space with newline character.

```
preg_replace('~\h~', '\n', $str);
```

`str_replace` alone would be enough for this job. But if you want to replace also the tabs, you must go with the above.

```
str_replace(' ', "\n", $str);
```

Comment: problem didn't solved.. I past the whole code... could you please take a look ?

Comment: put the replace function outside the for loop.

Comment: did that and here is the result ks392904.kimsufi.com. it only echo the last part of the string !!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str_replace` to do that.

```
$str = str_replace(" ", "\n", $str);
echo $str;
```

`\n` will do a linebreak.

Comment: I thought it doesn´t matter which string delimiter I use, as long as I am consequent and do not mix them.

Comment: Read again. Double quotes will preserve special characters, so that´s probably the better way to go.

Comment: problem didn't solved.. I past the whole code... could you please take a look ?